# JAXB marshlling is not ignoring namespace

Tags: java, jaxb, marshalling, xml-namespaces, unmarshalling

I have spent some time to investigate what is the problem but I couldn't solve it. When I unmarshal below XML and marshal back I see different XML.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<root>
 <one>test</one>
 <three>\MySG\test.jsp</three>
 <two>
    <st>
        <seeta>
            <Source>

                <problemtag xmlns="uuid:B89290D2-36FB-4EBC-A581-69B16D59EB92">
                    <p>deploy_test_page_renderingMetadata</p>
                </problemtag>
            </Source>
        </seeta>
        <Template id="tcm:1-63-32" title="Smart Compound Component Template"/>
        <Publication id="tcm:0-1-1" title="Publication"/>
    </st>
 </two>
</root>
```

- In the above xml only one tag (first one) expected remaining all (including namespace) are unexpected elements. Another application sends the above XML.

## My Mapping are like this

```
    package com.seeta.xml;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAnyElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

@XmlRootElement(name="root")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Root {
    @XmlElement(name="one")
    private String one;

    public String getOne() {
        return one;
    }

    public void setOne(String one) {
        this.one = one;
    }

    @XmlElement(name="three")
    private String three;

    @XmlAnyElement
    private List<Object> remaining = new ArrayList<Object>();


    public String getThree() {
        return three;
    }

    public void setThree(String three) {
        this.three = three;
    }

    public List<Object> getRemaining() {
        return remaining;
    }

    public void setRemaining(List<Object> remaining) {
        this.remaining = remaining;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return String.format("One [%s]-> Number of remaing elements [%d]-> three [%s]", one, remaining.size(), three);
    }
}
```

## Here is my simple code

```
package com.seeta.xml;

import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.StringWriter;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLDecoder;

import javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext;
import javax.xml.bind.JAXBException;
import javax.xml.bind.Marshaller;
import javax.xml.bind.Unmarshaller;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import javax.xml.parsers.ParserConfigurationException;
import javax.xml.transform.OutputKeys;
import javax.xml.transform.Transformer;
import javax.xml.transform.TransformerException;
import javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory;
import javax.xml.transform.dom.DOMSource;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamResult;

import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.xml.sax.InputSource;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;
        public class JaxbSample {

        public Document getDOMDocument(InputStream inputStream) throws ParserConfigurationException, SAXException, IOException {
            DocumentBuilderFactory documentBuilderFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
            documentBuilderFactory.setNamespaceAware(true);
            DocumentBuilder documentBuilder = documentBuilderFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
            if (inputStream != null) {
                return documentBuilder.parse(new InputSource(inputStream));
            } else {
                return documentBuilder.newDocument();
            }
        }
        public Root unmarshall(Document document) throws JAXBException {
            JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance(Root.class);
            Unmarshaller unmarshaller = context.createUnmarshaller();
            Root root = (Root) unmarshaller.unmarshal(document);
            return root;
        }

        public Document marshall(Root root) throws JAXBException, ParserConfigurationException, SAXException, IOException {
            JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance(Root.class);
            Marshaller marshaller = context.createMarshaller();
            Document document = getDOMDocument(null);
            marshaller.marshal(root, document);
            return document;
        }

        private String transform(Document document) throws TransformerException {
            StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
            TransformerFactory transformerFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
            Transformer transformer = transformerFactory.newTransformer();
            transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT, "yes");
            transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.OMIT_XML_DECLARATION, "yes");
            transformer.transform(new DOMSource(document), new StreamResult(sw));
            return sw.toString();
        }

        public void testUnmarshallMarshallUsingDocument() throws ParserConfigurationException, SAXException, IOException, JAXBException, TransformerException {
            InputStream inputStream = this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("jaxb.xml");
            Document document = getDOMDocument(inputStream);
            Root root = unmarshall(document);
            Document documentAfterMarshal = marshall(root);
            String output = transform(documentAfterMarshal);
            System.out.println(output);
        }

        public static void main(String[] args) throws ParserConfigurationException, SAXException, IOException, JAXBException, TransformerException {
            JaxbSample jaxbTest = new JaxbSample();
            jaxbTest.testUnmarshallMarshallUsingDocument();
        }
    }
```

## output is

```
    <root>
<one>test</one>
<three>\MySG\test.jsp</three>
<two>
<st>
<seeta>
<Source>
<problemtag:problemtag xmlns="uuid:B89290D2-36FB-4EBC-A581-69B16D59EB92" xmlns:problemtag="uuid:B89290D2-36FB-4EBC-A581-69B16D59EB92">
<p>deploy_test_page_renderingMetadata</p>
                </problemtag:problemtag>
            </Source>
        </seeta>
<Template id="tcm:1-63-32" title="Smart Compound Component Template"/>
<Publication id="tcm:0-1-1" title="Publication"/>
    </st>
 </two>
</root>
```

## And also I tried following

- I tried with NamespacePrefixMapper. I can able to give different namespace but not empty(""). I don't want any namespace at all.

new NamespacePrefixMapper() {
                public String getPreferredPrefix(String namespaceUri, String suggestion, boolean requirePrefix) {
                    return "";
                }
            };

- We don't have any xsd ( at least I don't know) in our project for trying unqualified thing
- I really didn't understand QName thing

Comment: There's something special with your `problemtag` and how it's mapped. Are you willing to share that part of the code too?

Comment: I have already shared it. Please check Root POJO. All tags are mapped to {{remaining}} except first tag (i.e., {{one}}).

Comment: Maybe it's only me, but I don't see any property called `problemtag` (neither `source` or a few others). Neither I can find any other property mapped to an XML element called `problemtag`.

Comment: All tags are mapped to {{remaining}} with @XmlAnyElement. So you don't see problemtag

Answer (score 0):

If all you want is to preserve the unused elements and marshall them back, I think you ought to be able to do something like this:

```
@XmlRootElement(name="Root")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
class Root {
    @XmlElement(name="One")
    private String one;

    @XmlAnyElement
    private List<Any> otherElements;
}

class AnyAdapter extends XmlAdapter<Element,Any> {
    @Override
    public Any unmarshal(Element element) throws Exception {
        return new Any(element);
    }

    @Override
    public Element marshal(Any any) throws Exception {
        return any.element;
    }
}

@XmlJavaTypeAdapter(AnyAdapter.class)
class Any {
    Element element;

    Any(Element element) {
        this.element = element;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> I don't want any namespace at all.

You won't be able to accomplish this with JAXB alone. The `@XmlAnyElement` tells the unmarshaller to dump the elements that it can't process into your list. Those elements have namespaces attached. When you then marshal those elements, they'll be written with their namespaces.

One option is for you to parse the incoming XML with a namespace-unaware DOM parser, then unmarshall it using the DOM tree. There's an example of this in the [`Unmarshaller` JavaDoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/Unmarshaller.html) (which uses a namespace-aware parser; it should be obvious what to change to make it namespace-unaware).

> I really didn't understand QName thing

Do you mean that you don't understand why the output is a qualified name, or why it picked the particular prefix? Or what QNames mean?

It's a qualified name because that's the most unambiguous way to represent the element.

I can't tell you why it picked this particular prefix; the JAXP serializer picks short names like "ns1", "ns2", and so on.

Comment: if you are referring to "setNamespaceAware(true|false)" then I tried but no luck :(

Comment: @SeetaRamayyaVadali - please show your *exact* code, as a compilable example program, with your *exact and complete* input and output. I find it very hard to believe that you took a DOM that could not have namespaces and unmarshalled it into an object that had namespaces.

Comment: Right now I am testing this as junit test case for easiness. So if I have to share the class means I need to share so many classes. So I'll create one and share with you tomorrow.

Comment: I can share my classes now. Please let me know how to share it with you. Is there any possibility to attach the source files here.

Comment: @SeetaRamayyaVadali - just edit your question to show the current code, *as well as the input and output files*. It really shouldn't be that large. If it is much larger than what you already have in your question, you need to trim it down: you should only need a dozen lines of code, and not much more for the input and output files.

Comment: @SeetaRamayyaVadali - your example code sets `namespaceAware(true)`. Do you understand why that cause the parser to preserve namespaces?

Comment: there is no difference if I set false to setNamespaceAware